# method arguments with date and integer types in java

Tags: java, date, methods

Hi I am new to Java please can anybody explain the following code. And I replaced int with the Date type but the d1 value doesn't changed. But why the date is only changing and how the setYear(100) is print as 2000.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  Date d1 = new Date(99,11,31);
  Date d2 = new Date(99,11,31);
  changeDate(d1,d2);
  System.out.println("d1: "+d1+" \nd2: "+d2);
}
static void changeDate(Date d1, Date d2){
  d1.setYear(100);
  d2 = d1;
}
```

d1 is Fri December 31 00:00:00 GMT 1999
d2 is Sun December 31 00:00:00 GMT 2000

Comment: `Date d1 = new Date(99,11,31);
  Date d1 = new Date(99,11,31);` Will it even compile ?

Comment: change second d1 to d2

Answer (score 0):

Java is reference by value. That means that the `d1` and `d2` Date objects in your `changeDate` method are different from the ones used in your `main` method, because they are method-specific (they are created in the method, not outside of it).

To fix this, you could declare `d1` and `d2` as class-wide variables and using those instead of the date objects in your methods.

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40499/3061857)

Answer (score 0):

```
d1.setYear(100);
```

Does refer to the object directly via the reference. Even if a copy of the reference is passed in the parameters, it still is able to access the object.

The method `setYear()` will change the year of your `Date` object to *1900 + the parameter*

That's why `d1.setYear(100)` is *2000 (1900 + 100)*

---

Why is d2 still referring to the same object?

Because inside your changeDate method, only the copy of the reference has been changed, not the original one.

[**More info**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score -2):

You have declared two times the object **d1**:

```
 Date d1 = new Date(99,11,31);
 Date d1 = new Date(99,11,31);
```

Maybe the second Date object should be d2.